# Dual screen PC downgraded to single screen, programs running on 2nd screen

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I recently downgraded my dual screen PC to single screen. I just turn off the PC, removed the video card and then hooked the large monitor into the on-board graphics card. Everything is working fine, but a couple of users moved our business app to the 2nd screen and now they can't see it when it runs as it has remembered which screen it was last on.

You can see the app is running in the task bar, but the window isn't visible. How do I get it back so that all apps run on the one screen without re-installing the Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Raymond Chen has discussed more than once, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to the app, and then either the old [<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> / <kbd>**M**ove</kbd> system menu trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/05/11/9601136.aspx) or the newer (Win7+) [<kbd>[image: 1]</kbd>+<kbd>**↑** (Up Arrow)</kbd> trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/22/10420443.aspx) to reposition windows that have wandered off-screen for whatever reason.

[Apparently](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/05/11/9601136.aspx#9625199) someone got so irritated with the state of affairs that he wrote an app called [SheepDog](http://sheepdog.codeplex.com) that can reposition all off-screen windows with a single hotkey combination:

[image: 2]

Comment: Thaks Mate, it worked for me.

Comment: Good to know! Also, since you're new here, don't forget to accept answers that helped you (using the green check mark to the left).