# How do I drag down a window in Windows 7 if the top bar is hidden (beyond the top part of the monitor)?

Tags: windows-7

This is the top of my monitor right now. How can I drag down the window? Please give a general solution that works for all programs (i.e., at the Windows layer), not just for Adobe Reader.

[image: This is the top of my monitor right now]

Comment: Duplicate of a question asked just yesterday (it's the exact same issue of off-screen/partially off-screen windows): [Dual screen PC downgraded to single screen, programs running on 2nd screen](http://superuser.com/questions/603632/dual-screen-pc-downgraded-to-single-screen-programs-running-on-2nd-screen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple ways come to mind, one of which is:

1. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right-click the icon in the taskbar.
2. Select `Move`.
3. Without using the mouse, use the arrow keys to move the window back on screen.

---

Another option is to maximize the window (again, by right-clicking it on the taskbar) and then drag the window down from the top of the screen. It will snap back to its larger size, although you will have the "top bar" visible so it will be resizeable.

Comment: i didnt know about the shift mode and now i finally know what that 4way arrow cursor means. thanks a lot.

Comment: A third option is to alt-tab to make the window active, and then alt-space.  This will bring up the same menu as the first option above.  Also, after using the arrow keys just once, you can then use the mouse to move, which can be useful if you have long distances to move.

Comment: Just a another tip, on step 3 you only have to hit any arrow key once, after that it will follow the mouse. Very useful for windows that where on a 2nd monitor then you RDP in and they still show up in the original location (which is now offscreen).